# Sqlite Search words between two words

Tags: string, sqlite, search

Simple explanation:

I have one column of text which is sentence in my book. How to find all the sentence who have words A X C  or X B C or A B X, where X can be any word.

Why I need this: More detail explanation

I am building trivia game. I got a book on my db, and I am generating questions where need to complete a word. So I am selecting a random sentence and removing a random word from it. This word is the current answer. And I want to give my users 3 random options to choose from. In order to do so, I want to search my book for similar words like this:

Lets say my sentence is A B C and the missing words is B. I want to find all the X words which are not B and are in my book between the words A and C.
Or lets say that the missing words is A. I want to find all the X words which are not A and are in my book after the words A. And same with C.

I have one column of text with is sentence in my book.

Comment: Is there a problem with the LIKE operator that prevents you from using that?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `%` would also match spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single mechanism that does what you want, and using `LIKE` or `GLOB` to scan the entire table probably is too slow anyway.

Try using a [full-text search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) to find records that have the two sentence fragments before and after the missing word.
Since these fragments should be almost adjacent, use the `NEAR` operator:

```
SELECT docid
FROM FtsTable
WHERE FtsTable MATCH '"a long time ago in a" NEAR/1 "far far away"'
```

This will still find records where there is no word between the two sentence fragments, or where the fragments are in the wrong order, so you still have to filter the result in your code.